# c# how to add string in of the line values in RichTextBox

Tags: c#

```
namespace PostingQueueMonitoring_V2
{
    public partial class Helper : Form
    {
        public Helper()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {  
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input_richTextBox1.Text.Trim()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please input text...");
                return;
            }

            string[] myText = new string[] {input_richTextBox1.Text};
            foreach (string element in myText)
            {
                output_richTextBox2.Text = element;
                System.Console.WriteLine(output_richTextBox2.Text);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();
            //output_richTextBox2.Rtf = input_richTextBox1.Rtf;
        }

        private void Helper_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MinimumSize = new Size(736, 466);
            this.MaximumSize = new Size(736, 466);
        }
    }
}
```

How to update the code that will format the text from input_richTextBox1 and shown in output_richTextBox2. Example below.

> input_richTextBox1:
>   Apple\n
>   Banna\n
>   Coconut\n
>   Durian\n
>   Orange
>
> Expected Result into output_richTextBox2
>   ('Apple',
>   'Banna',
>   'Coconut',
>   'Durian',
>   'Orange')

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried, output_richTextBox2.Text = "(" + element + ")"; but that is not what i expected. Trying search same request but no luck.

Comment: Never modify the Text property or you will mess up all formatting! Look into string.Split and RTB.Append

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox1.Text.Trim()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input text...");
            return;
        }

        var textValues = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').Select(txt => $"'{txt}'");
        var concatValues = string.Join(",", textValues);
        richTextBox2.Text = concatValues;
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
```